# How to get location of cell in DataGridView on control.MouseDown?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, mousedown

Currently I have a DataGridView, which the user can populate with a set of UserControls.  I've attached a handler for the control.MouseDown event to these Controls inside of the form.

The issue I am having is getting the cell's x and y indices.  I need to be able to get the column and row value but what I've tried isn't working.

This is the relevant snippet of code.

```
Private Sub MachineTaskMouseDownHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles eventClass.MachineTaskAttemptMove
    Debug.WriteLine("frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Raw: " & e.Location.ToString & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnX & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowY)
    Dim p2 As Point = Me.ScheduleDataGridView.PointToClient(e.Location)
    Debug.WriteLine("frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToClient: " & p2.ToString & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p2.X, p2.Y).ColumnIndex & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p2.X, p2.Y).RowIndex & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p2.X, p2.Y).ColumnX & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p2.X, p2.Y).RowY)
    Dim p3 As Point = Me.ScheduleDataGridView.PointToScreen(e.Location)
    Debug.WriteLine("frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToScreen: " & p3.ToString & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p3.X, p3.Y).ColumnIndex & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p3.X, p3.Y).RowIndex & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p3.X, p3.Y).ColumnX & " " & Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p3.X, p3.Y).RowY)
    Dim ht As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = Me.ScheduleDataGridView.HitTest(p.X, p.Y)
    from = New Point(ht.ColumnIndex, ht.RowIndex)
    Debug.WriteLine("frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Mouse down on control at " & from.ToString)
```

The above code is inconsistent.  Depending on where I click in a cell, the output changes.  For example, the output when clicking in the top left of cell (0,0):

```
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Raw: {X=10,Y=14} -1 -1 1 1
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToClient: {X=-228,Y=-92}-1 -1 -1 -1
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToScreen: {X=248,Y=120}1 1 197 95
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Mouse down on control at {X=-1,Y=-1}
```

As compared to clicking in the bottom right of the same exact cell:

```
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Raw: {X=148,Y=53} 0 0 42 22
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToClient: {X=-115,Y=-78}-1 -1 -1 -1
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToScreen: {X=411,Y=184}2 2 352 168
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Mouse down on control at {X=0,Y=0}
```

And just for the sake of completeness, here is the result of doing mouseDown in the bottom right of cell (1,0):

```
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Raw: {X=135,Y=61} 0 0 42 22
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToClient: {X=-103,Y=-45}-1 -1 -1 -1
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: ToScreen: {X=373,Y=167}2 1 352 95
frmSchedule.MachineTaskMouseDownHandler: Mouse down on control at {X=0,Y=0}
```

I just really need to get the cell location (row/col indices) based on a value from MouseEventArgs.

Comment: Sorry but it is not too clear from your attempts: do you want to get the x,y location of the given cell (with respect to the DataGridView or to the main form) or the associated row,col indices?

Comment: @varocarbas Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I wish to find the row/col indices of the cell.

Comment: Thanks (for unmarking). The code you are including (your tests and failures) is useful to show that you have put some effort into this (what is good);  but it is not too relevant for this problem. Post relevant parts of your code like how you are defining the DataGridView and why the CellClick event is not working in your situation.

Comment: @JPeroutek did you check out solution I provided?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you are seeking. The code below was a new project; dropped two `DataGridView` controls on the `Form` and populated them with fake data. Please see below.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        'Remove the added handlers don't forget...
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView Then
                RemoveHandler ctrl.MouseClick, AddressOf GetDataGridViewCellInfo
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Test Data ONLY'
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("FirstName", "First Name")
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("LastName", "Last Name")

        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Marilyn", "Manson")
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Bobby", "Grants")
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Shirley", "Thunderpots")

        'Add any handlers you need...
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView Then
                AddHandler ctrl.MouseClick, AddressOf GetDataGridViewCellInfo
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub GetDataGridViewCellInfo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim dgv As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)
            If dgv IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgv.CurrentCell IsNot Nothing Then
                'The form was just so I could show it by the cell ONLY...
                Dim frm As New Form
                frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
                Dim RowHeight1 As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Height
                Dim CellRectangle1 As Rectangle = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex, False)
                'Uncomment the two pieces at the end to show whatever you need at that point...
                CellRectangle1.X += dgv.Left '+ CellRectangle1.Width
                CellRectangle1.Y += dgv.Top '+ RowHeight1

                Dim DisplayPoint1 As Point = PointToScreen(New Point(CellRectangle1.X, CellRectangle1.Y))
                frm.Left = DisplayPoint1.X
                frm.Top = DisplayPoint1.Y
                frm.ShowDialog()
                frm.Dispose()

                MsgBox("Column Index: " & dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex & " Row Index: " & dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex & Environment.NewLine & "Cell Location = X:" & DisplayPoint1.X & " Y:" & DisplayPoint1.Y)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

I put some little comment's in the code. I used a `Form` to populate so I know its happening in the right place. You can see images reflecting the code from above.

**P.S. This is tried and tested**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]